# Question about Kile on Windows 10

Tags: windows, kile

I am using Kile Version 2.9.93 on Windows 10(27 inch Monitor 1080p), To my eye, the viewer for Kile is worse at rendering text when compared to TexMaker...

But Both Kile and TexMaker produce identical PDFs.

Viewer for Kile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhBCo.jpg

Viewer for TexMaker: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwatF.jpg

Is it me or the viewer for Kile is bad ? Anyways to improve the viewer on Kile ? (I have already tried "Configure Viewer" and "Configure Viewer Backends"

Comment: Maybe try https://kile.sourceforge.io/contact.php (forum, mailing list, ...) if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: "Kile and TexMaker produce identical PDFs"  That is because PDF quality depends only on the  quality of source code and compilation method, and that have nothing to do with the editor or the viewer. That said, at least in Linux it seems possible  to change the viewer in configuration in "Tools → Biuld → ViewPDF → Select Document Viewer → Okular,  Evince, ..."  and also in "Tools → Preview"  for the quick preview.